# Which kind of noun follows 'such as'?

Tags: grammar

> The government encourage residents to use transportation such as **bus/ buses**, **subway/ subways**, so on.

Is 'such as' followed by plural or singular nouns?

Comment: _Subway_ is a rail system rather than a single vehicle, so I wouldn't say subways, but I would say trains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think one is better than the other, but if you do choose singular, try to be consistent. Likewise, try to make them all plural if you prefer plural. At the same time, you can mix if necessary. As @VarunNair points out, there is only one subway system in a city. So if you prefer plural forms, your sentence might look like this:

> The government encourage**s** residents to use transportation such as buses, subway, trolley cars, and skateboards.

Comment: Thank you, I got your point. By the way, according to OALD, the goverment can be followed by both singular and plural verb.

Comment: @user8498054, feel free to mark the answer as '_accepted_' , if you think this answers your question.

Comment: You're welcome. I can only speak for American English, but it's pretty uncommon in America to hear government followed by a plural verb.

Comment: @user8498054: Correct (at least in BrE) - although if you were writing your sentence in BrE, you'd want to write "transport" rather than "transportation".  "Subway" also isn't usually used in this sense in BrE, although it might be used if discussing a US city or another city where "subway" is the conventional term or official translation.